# How to convert Open GL ES 2.0 to WebGL and/or Open GL?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, webgl, opengl-es-2.0, opengl-3

We have an iOS app that uses OpenGL ES to create a digital 3D model of a face. It is pretty sophisticated, but complex code. We are now wanting to create the same tool on a web application as well as on Mac OS. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to do this? It would be REALLY ideal if we could somehow take our OpenGL ES 2.0 code and convert it to WebGL/OpenGL to do this. Let me know if anyone has any suggestions on the best way(s).

Comment: on stackoverflow we generally don't like opinion based questions and software recommendation as those invite spam and make everyone unhappy. Anyway. Your answer is [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten)

Answer (score 0):

if you search for :

```
How Google Inbox shares 70% of its code
```

their solution is to write code in Android ready java which they then transcode into iOS ready Objective-C using http://j2objc.org and from java into web ready javascript using Google Web Toolkit SDK . Not entirely relevant since gmail is not 3D graphics, but I digress ...

For you immediate concerns, the modern approach is to shift the graphics heaving lifting out of normal CPU targeted OpenGL code and into shaders.  To the extent this is true your system, migration will be that much easier.  Since WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0 you should have minimum chaffing from OpenGL extensions not yet available in WebGL